# Laravel Throttling in Controller Class

Tags: controller, laravel-8, middleware, throttling

I am trying to implement throttling on my Laravel 8 application.  I have added the `configureRateLimiting()` method to the `RouteServiceProvider.php` file to limit unauthenticated requests to 20 per minute per IP address, as follows:

```
protected function configureRateLimiting() {
  Log::info( "Configuring..." );
  RateLimiter::for( 'global', function (Request $request) {
    Log::info( "Testing...");
    return $request->user()
      ? Limit::none()
      : Limit::perMinute(20)->by($request->ip());
  });
}
```

And I have added a constructor to my `Controller.php` file:

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->middleware('throttle:global');
}
```

I have not modified my `Kernel.php` file. The `ThrottleRequests` class is listed in the `web` `middlewareGroup`:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
  'web' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ],
...
```

My problem is that the `configureRateLimiting()` method is not getting called. The `"Configuring..."` message never shows in the log (neither does the `"Testing..."` message). Rate limiting is in effect, but it is always triggered, so I always see the `429` page, even immediately after running `php artisan cache:clear`.

Interestingly, If I change the `Controller` constructor to:

```
public function __construct() {
  Log::info( "In constructor." );
  $this->middleware('throttle:10,1');
}
```

I get throttled after 5 requests. And if I change the parameter to `throttle:20,1`, I get throttled after 10 requests. I always seem to get throttled after half the required number, even though the `"In constructor."` messaged is only logged once per request.

What have I missed? How do I get the `global` throttle working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that my `RouteServiceProvider.php` file had not been updated from Laravel 7, so the `boot()` method was not calling `configureRateLimiting()`. Once I switched it out for the Laravel 8 version, and added my custom code, everything started working as intended.